# How to add where between in the query?

Tags: php, database, laravel

in below query i need to get sum of only those product which are in between specific date how to add wherebetween query to get sum?

```
 $order =  Order::with('customer','product')->select('orders.id', 'orders.customer_id', 'orderdets.product_id', DB::raw('SUM(orderdets.quantity) as sum'))
    ->leftJoin('orderdets', 'orders.id', '=', 'orderdets.order_id')
    ->where('product_id', $scheme[0]->product_id)
    ->groupBy('orders.customer_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Not sure which language this is, but I assume you can just add 2 more where clauses. Or see if there is a between method

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like

```
$users = DB::table('users')
           ->whereBetween('votes', [1, 100])
           ->get();
```

check https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries to see any other ways to use where clauses